# How to give api count and date value to google line chart?

Tags: google-visualization, counter, linechart

I am making a simple web counter using count api. I am good in getting the counts. Now, I'm making a google line chart to show count value with the date in graph form. So, please help me how to set the date and count data in drawChart() function to get the count as per the date. And the graph should have 5 days of count. How to achieve this solution. Sincere Thanks in Advance!

```
const counter = document.getElementById('count');

updateVisitCount();

function updateVisitCount() {
  fetch('https://api.countapi.xyz/update/demo/sample/?amount=1').then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      counter.innerHTML = res.value;
    });
}

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Number of Site Visits'],
    
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Site Visits',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's working.

```
var counters=[
            ['string', 'value'],
            ];
         setInterval(()=>{
            fetch('https://api.countapi.xyz/update/demo/sample/?amount=1').then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
              
                var dt = new Date();
                var secs = dt.getSeconds() 
                counters.push(
                    [secs,res.value]
                )
                if(counters.length>3){
                    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 
                }
            });
         },1000);
        
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(counters);
        
            var options = {
                title: 'Site Visits',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
              };
        
            
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the graph keeps changing in the view every second irrespective with count.